# How can I migrate to worpress using my last blog's rss

Tags: rss, migration

I have all of the my blog's posts in a rss file and I want to copy them in my blog.How can I do this?!?

Answer (score 1):

There is plugin for importing content by RSS file, here's plugins page - [RSS Importer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-importer/)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work!

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I installed the plugin and I went to import menu and uploaded my rss file and after that I saw the message "All done Have fun" but I didn't see any change!!!

Comment: Tried RSS Importer and got similar result, but I exported test data from google reader and it's in json format. What's RSS file type? WordPress RSS Importer accepts only .xml files of RSS feed

Comment: this is my rss backup of my last blog: http://2barnamenevis.com/ahmadalli.mihanblog.com_1_12713588.xml

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee I think there format conflict, but I found Firefox add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/exporter/ using it you can export file in  WordPress eXtended RSS format and then easily import it using WordPress importer